# Minimum cut versus sparsest cut?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, network-flow

My question is that I'm trying to find the sparsest cut in a connected, undirected graph (all weights are = 1). Basically, I am looking trying to find the smallest cut (i.e., number of edges cut since all weights = 1) while maximizing the number of vertices in the resulting subgraph. How do I approach this problem with flow?

Comment: This problem is not well-defined yet.  You cannot minimize X while maximizing Y.  You need to pick a single metric to be optimized (e.g., maximize Y-X, or something).  You are going to find it difficult to solve the problem if you aren't even sure what solution you want.

Answer (score 2):

The sparsest cut problem, in which one attempts to minimize the ratio between the number of edges cut to the size of the smaller size of the bipartition, is NP-complete. The "last word" on this problem theoretically speaking is the $O(\sqrt{\log n})$ algorithm by Arora, Rao and Vazirani (affectionately knows as ARV), which has found many uses in the area of approximation algorithms.

You might want to start with the simpler algorithm of Leighton and Rao, which gives an $O(\log n)$ approximation and has a relation to flows. See for example [these lecture notes](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/rraj/Courses/7880/S12/Lectures/UniformMCF2.pdf), or many others.